# Implementation-less typed factory issues

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Take this simple example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        windsorContainer.Install(new WindsorInstaller());

        var editor = windsorContainer.Resolve<IEditor>();
        editor.DoSomething();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(Component.For<ISomeOtherDependency>().ImplementedBy<SomeOtherDependency>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IReviewingService>().ImplementedBy<ReviewingService>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IEditor>().ImplementedBy<Editor>());
        container.Register(Component.For<Func<IReviewingServiceFactory>>().AsFactory());
    }
}

public interface IEditor
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Editor : IEditor
{
    private readonly Func<IReviewingServiceFactory> _reviewingService;

    public Editor(Func<IReviewingServiceFactory> reviewingService)
    {
        _reviewingService = reviewingService;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var rs = _reviewingService();
        var reviews = new List<string> {"Review #1", "Review #2"};
        var reviewingService = rs.Create(reviews);

        reviewingService.Review();
    }
}

public interface IReviewingServiceFactory
{
    IReviewingService Create(IList<string> reviews);
}

public interface IReviewingService
{
    void Review();
}

public class ReviewingService : IReviewingService
{
    private readonly IList<string> _reviews;
    private readonly ISomeOtherDependency _someOtherDependency;

    public ReviewingService(IList<string> reviews, ISomeOtherDependency someOtherDependency)
    {
        _reviews = reviews;
        _someOtherDependency = someOtherDependency;
    }

    public void Review()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reviewing...");
    }
}

public interface ISomeOtherDependency
{
}

public class SomeOtherDependency : ISomeOtherDependency
{
}
```

With this example I would expect the console to output "Reviewing...". However, Windsor throws exceptions:

```
No component for supporting the service CastleWindsorTypedFactor.IReviewingServiceFactory was found
```

What is wrong with my Windsor installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You registered `Func<IReviewingServiceFactory>` instead of `IReviewingServiceFactory`... try replacing

```
container.Register(Component.For<Func<IReviewingServiceFactory>>().AsFactory());
```

with

```
container.Register(Component.For<IReviewingServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
```

and adapt the code accordingly - then it should work.

Oh, and another thing - you registered your `IReviewingService` without specifying a lifestyle, which will default to SINGLETON. That is most likely *not* what you want, because then your `reviews` argument will only be passed to the instance *when is gets created*, which only happens the first time the factory is called...! Additional calls to the factory will return the singleton instance.

Therefore: Change the lifestyle of `IReviewingService` to transient, AND create an appropriate release method signature on the factory interface (e.g. `void Destroy(IReviewingService service)`).

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that if my constructor argument was `Func<T>` then I had to register `Func<T>` and not only `T`. I only had the change what I registered with Windsor and not `Func<IReviewingServiceFactory>` from my constructor argument as I want it to be lazy loaded. Thank you.

Comment: If you want your editor to have `Func<IReviewingServiceFactory>` injected, then yes - you need to register the `Func`. But there's really no reason why you would go through the extra step of invoking a `Func` to get the factory when you could just have an `IReviewingServiceFactory` injected.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for updating your answer.